# how to search values like (10,000 and 20,000 and 25,000) in mysql using php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using php and jquery for ajax

I have a salary column in my mysql employee table and this column contains salary in the form of(10,000 and 20,000 and 25,000 etc).
My question is how to search for the salary :
-less than 10,000
-between 10,000 to 20,000 or something else
-more than 1 lac

using php.

I have used "select salary from employee where salary < 10,000" and 
"select salary from employee  where salary < 10000"
but it is not working.

Here is my source code:

```
$sql    =   mysqli_query($con,"select salary from employee where salary < 
10,000"); 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
        {
           echo $row['salary'];
        }
```

Can anyone help me please

Answer (score 0):

Here's what to change

Instead of

```
        if($("#FullTime").prop("checked"))
        {   
            var r = $(this).val();
```

Use

```
        if($("#FullTime").prop("checked"))
        {   
            var r = $("#FullTime").val();
```

Your problem is that you're checking whether a specific checkbox is checked, then sending the value of the checkbox that has *just been clicked* rather than the value of the checkbox that is checked.

You will need to make a similar change to the code in the other click event.

Comment: Thank you for your precious time but what does ' in the other click event ' mean in your statement

Comment: There's actually only one click event, so I wrote that wrong. What I mean is in this piece of code:
`if($("#PartTime").prop("checked"))
            {
                var r = $(this).val();`

Comment: I did the changes told by you but still the problem is occurring friend

Comment: I think your code has a lot of problems. I don't know what `filter2.php` does, or what it returns. But there are a total of three different ajax calls that write to `$("#res").html(data);` Try separating them out so they write to different divs.